# PostgreSQL Insert timestamp using today's date but specific hour

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

I had this statement for SQLSERVER which inserts into a DateTime column, today's date but a specific hour.

```
INSERT INTO session VALUES(
SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), DAY(GETDATE()), 12, 0), 1, 1);
```

I am trying to achieve the same result in PostgreSQL but I can only find this

```
INSERT INTO sessions VALUES(current_timestamp, 1, 1)
```

Which inserts the current date and time.

How would I be able to do this in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
current_date + interval '12 hour'
```

Note:  When you insert values into a table, you should always list the columns for the insert.

Comment: Alternatively: `current_date + time '12:00:00'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this :

```
NOW() + interval '12 hour'
```

Comment: Yeah but it will not set the 12 as an hour of the date but it will actually move the current time over 12 hours. so if you are inserting at 1:23am you will receive time 1:23pm